# Attachments issue when forwarding an email using VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a RibbonXML which provide a context menu that takes an action  on a received email. That email contains a spreadsheet attachment, and I want to update that spreadsheet (xlsx) and forward it to another recipient...

What is happening is that the recipient see two attachments, one being usually quite small (a few KB), and the other being the correct attachment. This does the same thing with pdf, or text files, so pretty sure it isn't the file type. It shows up in the attachments list in the email inspector, but if you try to do anything with it Outlook says the attachment cannot be found.

I built up the test from scratch and added in components of my solution until the error was found. It *seems* to be related to removing attachments from the new email item (resulting from the Forward() method).

```
    public void OnTestAttachment(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        if (control.Context is Selection)
        {
            Selection selection = control.Context as Selection;
            if (selection.Count == 1)
            {
                object item = selection[1];
                if (item is MailItem)
                {
                    MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;
                    var newItem = mailItem.Forward();
                    newItem.Recipients.Add("xxxxx@xxxxx.com");
                    var newAttachments = newItem.Attachments;

                    // remove the line below and I don't see the issue
                    for (int i = newAttachments.Count; i >= 1; i--) { newAttachments.Remove(i); }
                    {
                        var body = "Testing.....\r\n";
                        MSWord.Document document = (MSWord.Document)newItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
                        MSWord.Paragraph paragraph = document.Paragraphs.Add(document.Range());
                        paragraph.Range.Text = body;
                    }

                    // do some things with a file..in prod I save the existing file, edit it via code and then save it back down....
                    // I tested using a byte stream in case that has something to do with the issue (as that's the closest 
                    // match to what is actually going on in prod)
                    var fileName = @"C:\Users\<me>\Test.xlsx";
                    var temp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                    byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                    newAttachments.Add(temp, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    // the issues doesn't appear here...it is only once it is received that it appears
                    newItem.Display();

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newItem);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newAttachments);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                }
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection);
        }
```

Comment: What is the content of the small file? If you open it in notepad, what do you see?

Comment: When using an xlsx file, it was a bunch of random stuff (not a valid zip file), but I then tried it with a .txt file and that's when it just couldn't be opened (Outlook says there was a problem accessing the object)..

Comment: I am inclined to believe that it has to do with the line of code that removes the attachments...in prod I have changed to Reply() instead of forward which ignores the attachments from the very start...so I'm pretty sure it isn't the way I'm attaching new files, but how they're being removed.  Maybe I need to remove the attachments differrently?

Comment: Can you do `newAttachments.Clear()`?

Comment: Clear() doesn't appear to be a method which can be called via the PIA.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments?view=outlook-pia

Comment: Can you see the bad attachment details in OutlookSpy (I am its author - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on the attachment. The way you remove the attachments seems fine to me. Not sure though why you modify the message body using Inspector and Word Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

> It shows up in the attachments list in the email inspector, but if you try to do anything with it Outlook says the attachment cannot be found.

The Outlook object model is not related to the issue described. The file can be overwritten with an empty data and then can be attached to the email:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

The following sentence confirms this:

> What is happening is that the recipient see two attachments, one being usually quite small (a few KB), and the other being the correct attachment.

If you need to cope the file content I'd suggest saving the file using the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method of the `Attachment` class which saves the attachment to the specified path. Thus you can be sure the file content is not empty.